# Vertical line character for tree visualizing

Tags: pdf, tree, character

I am making a tree structure in a pdf file and I want it to look like this but without a gap between the vertical line and the underscores:

```
1
|___11
|_______111
|___12
2
|___21
|___22
```

Does anyone know of a character to replace the vertical line with one that is right aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you want a text-based tree-like structure like the `tree` command in command prompt produces.

ASCII character 192 '└' or 195 '├' will do the job.
Have a look at the [extended ASCII table](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/E/extended_ASCII.html).

I don't fully understand the *right aligned* in your question.

Comment: If the vertical line would be right aligned instead of centered, it wouldn't have that ugly gap.